# Jmeter: HTML report generation after tests

Tags: jmeter, report, jmeter-plugins

These are the steps that I followed to generate reports:

1. I have the `.jtl` file
2. I copy paste given [sample configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#sample_configuration) to my `user.properties` file located at `apache-jmeter-5.0\bin`
3. I convert `.jtl` to aggregate report using `CMDRunner.jar`

   ```
   java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv Demo17Results.csv --input-jtl Demo17Results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```
4. Convert `csv` file got from step#3 to HTML reports

   **I tried (1)**   `jmeter -g Demo17Results.csv -o htmlReports/`

`Error: csv' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly when generating report
An error occurred: Mismatch between expected number of columns:17 and columns in CSV file:11, check your jmeter.save.saveservice.* configuration or check line is complete`

**I tried (2)** `jmeter -n -t Demo17Run.jmx -l Demo17Results.csv -e -o htmlReports/`

`Creating summariser <summary>
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Results file:Demo17Results.csv is not empty`

after emptying the csv file

`Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using Demo17Run.jmx
Starting the test 
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not read metadata !
... end of run`

What am I doing wrong to generate Jmeter HTML dashboard reports?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need step 2, JMeter default configuration is just fine for dashboard generation
2. You don't need step 3, the dashboard needs to be created from the `Demo17Results.jtl` file which contains **full raw** results, not statistics table
3. Try re-running your test scenario with [forcing deletion of the previous result file via `-f` argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options):

   ```
   jmeter -n -f -t Demo17Run.jmx -l Demo17Results.jtl -e -o htmlReports/
   ```

If nothing helps double check you have not modified required [results file configuration settings](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements) and [increase JMeter logs verbosity for `report.dashboard` package](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard" level="debug" />
```

Comment: If I use it with `-f` argument the index.html is (reports are created) created blank and no error, but if I skip the `-f` argument from command it gives a message that `.jtl is not empty` and reports are not created.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Logs were very big so added in this open link. Please check.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j_Nz5kdAVFqdo0dVkKY7qyPL6xBPubolzHFhqnvt7Bo/edit

Comment: `Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File csv1.csvmust exist and be readable`. Your dashboard is empty because your test is not executed due to not being able to find `csv1.csv` and `csv2.csv` files, double check your [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) settings and make sure that the files are present in appropriate places.

Comment: It did run fine. I am using the same `.jtl` file to extract aggregate report. See step#3 where I used `CMDRunner.jar`. However, I didn't get what you mean by `make sure that the files are present in appropriate places`. Jmeter is in environment variables and for files, I am putting correct path in command.

Comment: According to the log you shared it didn't

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when I was trying to generate the HTML dashboard report after the test run.  Even though the path to the .jtl file was correct (and there were no spaces in the directory names), I was getting that error “Mismatch between expected number of columns...” I was pointing the command to a copy of the .jtl file I had made in another directory. I changed the command to pick up the .jtl file that was in JMeter\bin and that worked… no more error and the reports were generated. So, the command (run from JMeter\bin) that worked was: jmeter –g log.jtl –o C:\HTML_Reports.

Also, the output folder that is specified must not exist (JMeter will create it) or if it does exist, it must be empty.