# Jmeter: How to create HTML dashboard in jmeter using saved summary csv file

Tags: jmeter

I am using following command to generate HTML dashboard:

`jmeter -g  C:/Users/E01659/Desktop/feb28/feb28_10_3600.csv -o  C:/Users/E01659/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/sonali/`

> Following error is coming: File
>   'C:\Users\E01659\Desktop\feb28\feb28_10_3600.csv' does not contain the
>   field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties
>   are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read
>   incorrectly when generating report An error occurred: Mismatch between
>   expected number of columns:17 and columns in CSV file:11, check your
>   jmeter.save.saveservice.* configuration or check line is complete
>   errorlevel=1

Comment: please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862281/jmeter-html-report-generation-after-tests

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it is clear that - CSV file created earlier don't have the header as the first line. When you want to create the APDEX Dashboard from CSV file, JMeter expects that files are created with correct [Save Service Configuration](http://ps://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements). You can change  [Result file config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) which are present in `jmeter.propertes` file.

You may need to change the line as below, so that file created has the headers name as required

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.label = true
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you're using is [correct](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only), the reason of failure is mismatch of the .jtl file contents and what JMeter expects it to be.

If you got this `feb28_10_3600.csv` file from execution on another JMeter installation - make sure that JMeter's [result save configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) on the machine where you're trying to generate the report is identical to the JMeter installation where JMeter was running.

Inspect the associated [JMeter properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) and amend them to for 100% match, once done you should be able to normally generate the dashboard.

If you still experience the differences update your question with first 2-3 lines of your .jtl results file.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error (most likely) due to a corrupt line at the end of your file. Just execute a 'tail ' to see the last few lines. Most likely, your last line is missing columns due to an abrupt stop in the test. Once you delete the problematic line, you should be able to generate the HTML report.